# Is there a standard argument sequence identity function in Clojure?

Tags: function, clojure, sequence, identity, arity

Is there a function in the Clojure standard library equivalent to the following?

```
(fn [& args] args)
```

If not, why?

Example usage:

```
(take 10 (apply (fn [& args] args) (range)))
;=> (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)

;; ironically, map isn't lazy enough, so let's take it up to 11
(defn lazy-map [f & colls]
  (lazy-seq (cons (apply f (map first colls))
                  (apply lazy-map f (map rest colls)))))

(defn transpose [m]
  (apply lazy-map (fn [& args] args) m))

(defn take-2d [rows cols coll]
  (take rows (map (partial take cols) coll)))

(take-2d 3 3 (transpose (map (partial iterate inc) (range))))
;=> ((0 1 2) (1 2 3) (2 3 4))
```

Please note that I am not asking for a transformative, eager function such as `vector` or `list`.

Comment: Your function is *exactly* equivalent to `list`. I can't see a difference: what makes `list` "transformative" and yours not?

Comment: @coredump- Try `(type ((fn [& args] args) :foo))` and `(type (list :foo))`.

Comment: @Elogent in idiomatic clojure the exact subtype is rarely important - you'll find that the two collections are `=` and that they share all the same important interfaces.

Comment: All arguments are evaluated before calling a function, so I do not really understand what laziness has to do here. But maybe you could detail a little bit what you have in mind?

Comment: @coredump- *Evaluated*, yes, but if an argument happens to be a sequence, it is not *realized*. Try the first example in the updated question replacing the sequence identity function with `list` or `vector` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Elogent In fact no argument is a sequence here. For any function *fn*  when you do `(apply fn (range))` you are calling *fn* with an infinite number of non-sequential arguments. But you have a point and I will edit the answer to reflect this particular aspect.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate it if the downvoters would actually leave a comment on *why* this question is bad. If there's something wrong with my way of thinking, *tell me what it is* instead of just downvoting the question and leaving me scratching my head about what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such function, you are free to implement and use it as you like:

```
(defn args [& args] args)

(set (map type (apply map args [[1 2 3][4 5 6][7 8 9]])))
=> #{clojure.lang.ArraySeq}
```

*Why isn't it already available?*

This is rarely fruitful question: not only we don't know what happens in the mind of implementors, it is impracticable to ask them to justify or document why they did *not* do something. Was adding this function ever considered? How can we know? Is there really a reason, or did it just happen?

On the other hand, I agree that `args` feels simpler because it passes around an already existing immutable sequence. 
I also can understand if you think that *not* converting the arguments as a persistent list in the first place is better, if only for the sake of parcimony.

But this is not how it is implemented, and the overhead of using `list` is really negligible (and [specialized](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/5189fdae8c4a010482de4c30e7926adadaaa43ee/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentList.java#L27) when building from an instance of `ArraySeq`).
You are supposed to code to an interface and never look behind the curtain, and from this point of view, `list` and `args` are *equivalent*, even though they do not return *identical* results.

You added a remark about laziness, and you are right: if you ever need to take the arguments from a variadic function and pass it to a function which operates on sequences, The version with `list` will consume all the given arguments whereas `args` will not. In some cases, as with `(apply list (range))`, where you literally pass an infinite number of arguments, this might hang forever.

From that point of view, the little `args` function is in fact interesting: you can move from arguments to actual sequences without introducing potential problems.
I am however not sure how often this case happens in practice.
In fact, I have a hard time finding a use case where laziness in the argument list really matters as far as `args` is concerned.
After all, in order to pass an infinite sequence, the only way (?) is to use apply:

```
(apply f (infinite))
```

In order to have a use-case for `args`, that means that we want to convert from an argument list back to a single list so that another function *g* can use it as a sequence, like so:

```
(g (apply args (infinite)))
```

But in that case, we could directly call:

```
(g (infinite))
```

In your example, `g` would stand for `cons` inside `lazy-map`, but since `f` is given in input, we cannot write `(cons (map ...) ...)` directly. The example thus looks like a genuine use case for `args`, but you should document the function heavily because the snippet you gave is quite complex. I tend to think that giving an unbounded number of arguments to a function is a code smell: should every function with an `[& args]` signature avoid consuming all arguments because the given sequence might in fact be infinite, like `lazy-map` does? I'd rather have a single argument be a lazy sequence for this kind of usage (and pass `identity` where needed) instead of the whole argument list, to clarify the intent. But in the end, I am not strongly opposed to the use of `args` either.

So to conclude, unless you manage to convince Rich Hickey to add `args` as a core function, I am confident that almost nobody will want to depend on an external library which does just this<sup>**1**</sup>: it is unfamiliar, but also trivial to implement and mostly useless. The only reward is knowing that you skip a little transformation step which costs nothing in most cases. Likewise, do not worry about having to choose between a vector and a list: it has practically no influence on your code and you can still modify the code later if you can prove it is necessary.
Regarding laziness, while I agree that wrapping arguments in lists or vectors can be problematic with unbounded argument lists, I am not sure the problem actually arises in practice.

---

**1**. Of course, if it ever reaches `clojure.core`, everybody will be quick to say that is is a fundamental operation which is most useful and definitely idiomatic *</cynic>*

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I only have one more question: use of lists for storing general data is [discouraged](https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide#avoid-lists), so it would seem that `vector` is therefore the best option. But since vectors print differently from other sequences, someone who plays with one of my functions in a REPL could quite possibly be tempted to treat the return value as a vector (and, e.g., call `get` on it). How should I decide between `list` and `vector` in this case?

Comment: The style guide you link has many good *recommendations*, but some of them are void of any justifications. In particular, the part about lists is quite ambiguous. My interpretation is: people hear that Lisp is all about lists, which is false, and can be tempted to stuff everything in them instead of using records, maps, etc., hence the suggestion to avoid defaulting to lists. But this is true for vectors too (notice the guide does not say "use vectors instead"). There is no option which is best in all cases. In your example, you could use vector since the input is made of vectors.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience on this question. I added a further example of laziness in the OP; does my `transpose` function fall under the "no use case for `args`" reasoning you explained? If so, could you discuss that a bit further in your answer? Am I taking this laziness thing too far?

Comment: @Elogent Your updated use case was a little bit hard to follow, honestly, but I understand why `args` is actually required there. My only problem is that `lazy-seq` makes an explicit efforts to avoid accessing all the arguments, which is something that is rarely found IMHO. Typically, functions take arguments parameters as a finit (small) set of inputs.

Comment: That's pretty much what I was thinking as well. I believe you've quite thoroughly answered my question; thanks very much for your insight! :)

Answer (score 1):

There's `identity` function. It takes an argument and just returns that argument. Clojure's `identity` is single arity though.

usage:

`(identity 4) ;=> 4`

`(identity [1 2 3 4]) ;=> [1 2 3 4]`

I don't think there's much sense in having the identity function with variable arity since Clojure functions return only one value. If you want to return multiple values from a function, then you can wrap them in a seq which you can later destructure. In that case you can have something like this:

```
(defn varity-identity [& args]
    (map identity args))
```

`(varity-identity 1 2 3 4 5) ;=> (1 2 3 4 5)`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I gave an implementation of the desired function in my question, and your `varity-identity` function doesn't even do the same thing as that function (try calling `type` on the result returned by each). This does not answer my question.

Comment: varity-identity returns a different type, a LazySeq due to the usage of map, but it does the same thing as your function. Both functions take a bunch of arguments, and return those arguments as a seq. if you run `(apply map varity-identity [[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]])` you will see that it returns the same output as the one you've given in your question.

Comment: @Elogent Also in your question, you're asking if there's a function in the standard lib that is equivalent `(fn [& args] args)`. I explained `identity` and how you can use it to make it work for variable arity which gives the same effect as the function you provided. Therefore, I believe I answered what the question asked for.

Comment: I believe that you misunderstood the word "equivalent". Obviously I can do whatever I want with the tools in Clojure (see the function definition that I wrote in the original question), but that's not what I'm asking. I'm asking if there is a standard function that does *exactly* the same thing as the function I provided. You have given neither such a function nor an explanation of why one does not exist (considering the fact that application of a function to a sequence is a [native operation in `IFn`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/IFn.java#L95)).

Comment: @Elogent - I don't think there's a function to create an `ArraySeq` directly similar to `list` or `vector` since it seems to be an implementation detail you shouldn't depend on. So you can either use your function or some other concrete seq type.

Comment: @Lee My goal is not to make use of implementation details like `ArraySeq` but rather, since sometimes I don't care about the type of the sequence I produce, to avoid creating new implementation details by deciding between `list`, `vector`, or some other concrete type. I also think such a function would make code that uses it more readable and semantically meaningful.

Comment: If you don't care about the type of the sequence, then what's wrong with `list` or `vector`? Your function is just as "transformative": `(class (apply map (fn [& args] args) ['(1 2 3) '(4 5 6) '(7 8 9)])) ;=> clojure.lang.LazySeq`, where `'(1 2 3)` is a `clojure.lang.PersistentList`.  All of these functions construct sequences.  Yours doesn't always return the same kind of sequence, but it has to make a choice in order to construct a sequence, and it would be unClojurely to for it have to match the class of some of its arguments (cf. noisesmith's comment).  What about `[[1 2 3] '(4 5 6)]`?